# Possible vulnerability for full frontend app connecting to localhost:*

Tags: web-browser, exploit

I was attempting to connect to a server that hosts my client-side app, and when using the localhost URL I am able to connect to my local dev environment instead of the servers localhost. I was wondering if this was a known vulnerability, if one at all? 
Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't really sound like a vulnerability. Can you clarify what you did, and how what you saw differs from what you expected?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was trying to figure out why a client-side app was connecting to a server-side socket intermittently using socket.io. Both apps were hosted from the same server, I had the client-side apps sockets pointed to localhost:3000. My server-side app was listening on port 3000 but it wouldn't connect. However when I had the dev-server-side app running, which was located on my local machine, the client-side app did connect and executed the dev-server-side app's sub routines. I was wondering if that was a vulnerability.

Comment: When turn on something and then are able to connect to it is the expected behaviour.  We have absolutely no clue what you're doing, we do not know your app, your server or your environment.  Do not expect people to read minds through the wire.

Comment: Does your "client-side app" run on the client (your local machine) or the server? If it runs on the client, as the name suggests, and you configure it to point at localhost, yes, it will indeed connect to the localhost on the client computer (how would it even know where the server is?)

Comment: please forgive me my noobiness, It was unexpected for me at first, but it makes complete sense now. A full client side application would use the clients local machine and therefor localhost would be relative to the clients location and local computer where the browser is running. I was wondering if it caused a threat, couldn't a malicious client-side application send requests or intercept things from the users browser or perhaps talk to a service on a  local ip address?